# Xamarin Forms App crashes after splash screen on iOS device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin Forms App works fine in Android devices, but when trying do deploy on a real iOS device it crashes after the splash screen, I said real because I can run without any problem on the simulator.

I try to debug the App on a real iOS device, and I found that the crash happen when the App try to load the XAML file on:

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(LoginPage));
```

**Please take a look at the debug steps:**

[image: Debug Starting...]

[image: Crash Happens]

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: There is something wrong in your XAML, enable the XAML compiler to try to catch it at compile time.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your xaml code (and page init if there is)... But there is probably A mistake in your LoginPage xaml or code behind (do you initialize something in your LoginPage - in constructor or Loaded ?)

Comment: I found the problem. The [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] was missing on the code behind C# file, and because of that some methods used by click events of controls on the XAML were not available. But still can't find explanation for this not happening on the simulator!

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. The [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] was missing on the code behind C# file, and because of that some methods used by click events of controls on the XAML were not available. But still can't find explanation for this not happening on the simulator!

Answer (score 0):

In case it is a help to anyone, I had the same symptom for a different reason.  I am using single page simple navigation in the app in question setting MainPage to the current page in the app.  After few days of troubleshooting, happened to notice the checkbox in Application section of info.plist, "Supports Multiple Windows" was checked.  Unchecking this restored my app to working condition.  There were no diagnostic messages that seemed related, just a crash after splash in release mode, and a black screen in debug mode.